# Broken & Offline RAID10 - Array How to Add Drives Back (AMD RaidXpert)

Tags: hardware-raid, raid-10

I have a RAID10 array using 4 drives on an AMD Chipset controller (890FX). I had to unplug my drives to replace a failed water pump and when I booted up realised I hadn't plugged one drive in properly. I saw that [this guy](https://superuser.com/questions/438840/how-to-fix-missing-raid1-drive?newreg=4f7947fa8d2f4c5a91373796ac57a1c7) had the same thing happen so I followed the accepted answer, got AMD RaidXpert installed and proceeded to rebuild the array. I left it rebuilding overnight, however this morning I awoke to find that Windows 10 had automatically installed updates and rebooted itself. Fantastic.

Now I have an offline array and according to the setup only two drives are now in the array. I have no options to rebuild or start the array or assign drives. The HW ROM / BIOS setup page is pretty useless and RaidXpert has all the options greyed out.

I've rebooted several times, powered off and on, checked the bios settings for the ports are RAID, entered the ROM config (not that that is very useful except to view the status). I have no idea how to restore the array now. It's been stuck on 82% rebuild for several hours now.

Mobo is ASUS Crosshair IV Formula, AMD Chipset SATA Controller version 3.7.1540.43, Windows 10 Pro (now 2004)

[Screenshot of RaidXpert physical drive assignments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuS3R.png)

[Screenshot of RaidXpert logical drive array status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eG80.png)

[Screenshot of RaidXpert logical drive Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH8SC.png)

Comment: Couple posts to read with one being here: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/raid-5-building-stuck-a-0.3424364 and potentially disconnecting and reconnecting drives and then starting up might help it move. And the other is here: https://community.amd.com/thread/247570 with some potential command line commands to run and it also talks about some a RAID configuration web interface rather than the app being helpful just in case these help, they are likely worth you reading the thread and everyone's comments, etc.

Comment: Don't worry about the RAID configuration so much RAID 5 vs RAID 10 with what those posts talk about, just the symptoms of the issues explained with configuring RAID or getting it to rebuild and potentially helpful tips to get you thru this problem.